# Programmatically creating TeamTab used to work, but now gives error after updating Libraries

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Could you help me on what I am missing out for getting this error when I am creating a Team Tab programmatically? The code used to work until I updated the graph libraries to a higher level from the previous ones.

```
Code: BadRequest
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 09211d2b-ed86-4f89-8667-42f749521af1
    date: 1/17/2020 8:41:28 AM
ClientRequestId: 09211d2b-ed86-4f89-8667-42f749521af1
```

Below is the code which has run always until I updated the packages but now giving errors.

```
            //Creates Tab object for Dashboard
            TeamsTab teamsDashboardTab = new TeamsTab()
            {
                DisplayName ="My Dashboard",
                TeamsAppId = AppId,
                Configuration = new TeamsTabConfiguration
                {
                    EntityId = AppId,
                    ContentUrl = TargetServer + project.Id,
                    WebsiteUrl = TargetServer + project.Id
                }
            };

var teamsTab = await _graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(teamsDashboardTab);
```

Also below is the current versions of the graph libraries that I am using.

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="1.0.0-preview.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Beta" version="0.9.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: I don't know why that is happening for you, but when I get a strange error with the SDK client, I have found that it is a good idea to have an alternate method for calling the graph api directly. I can then use that method to isolate what's going on.. You can even use the graphclient to authenticate your http session easily.  Take a [look](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library)

Comment: Hi @ChadCarlton so the alternate methods I have tried is to change the package versions which works currently, but the tradeoff is that The user Presence class is not in that package. This is the package versions that works for tab creation now, `Microsoft.Graph.Auth version=1.0.0-preview.1, Microsoft.Graph.Beta version=0.8.0-preview, Microsoft.Graph.Core version=1.17.0 and Microsoft.Identity.Client version=4.3.1`

Comment: the tab still gets created, but throws an exception. You could try catch it until Microsoft fix the bug!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to add new Website tab to channel.

To make it work I had to set `ODataType` to `null` in `TeamsTabConfiguration`. The code should look like this:

```
var tab = await _graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs.Request().WithMaxRetry(3).AddAsync(
new TeamsTab
{
    DisplayName = TabTitle,
    ODataBind = $"{_teamsFactory.GraphV1Endpoint}/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web",
    Configuration = new TeamsTabConfiguration
    {
        ODataType = null,
        EntityId = null,
        WebsiteUrl = $"{_appUrl}/1",
        ContentUrl = $"{_appUrl}/1",
        RemoveUrl = null
    }
});
```

It is only a workaround. It is labeled as "service bug" on GitHub ([issue#598](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/598))